# Is dynamic user equilibrium (duaRouter) compatible with FLOW?

Tags: flow-project

In the grid example, I found vehicles are not turning and routes are fixed. Is there any method to let vehicles iteratively find 'shortest path'? I mean, can we implement dynamic user equilibrium when using FLOW?

SUMO provides duaIterate.py, can anyone provide some insights on how to incorporate that in FLOW experiment? 
Thank you in advance.